# PHP 5.3 and sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php

Deal All, 
i have follow issue: i would like to connect to ms sqlserver2008 with php function.
In the past it works fine with mssql_connect. 
Since i have updated to php 5.3 i have an array issue:

Syntax:

```
$serverName = "sql server"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "db", "user", "pw");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
 exit;
```

When i will show the page, i get this array error:

```
 Connection could not be established.
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -8 [code] => -8 [2] => An 
invalid connection option key type was received. Option key types must be strings. 
[message] => An invalid connection option key type was received. Option key types must be strings. ) )
```

Maybe somebody has an idea ? For this I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Check the **[MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)**. The connectionInfo should be a key/value pairs array:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the array definition, try this:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pw");
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are enclosing parameters into double quotes too.

**Incorrect Syntax:**

- `$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"$this->db_name", "UID"=>"$this->user_name", "PWD"=>"$this->user_pwd");`
- `$connectionInfo = array("Database=>$this->db_name", "UID=>$this->user_name", "PWD=>$this->user_pwd");`

**Correct Syntax:**

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$this->db_name, "UID"=>$this->user_name, "PWD"=>$this->user_pwd);
```

**Complete Code Should be as below**

```
<?php
class db_config{
private $server_name = "BITCODES\SQLEXPRESS";
private $user_name = "ERPSA";
private $user_pwd = "ERP@123";
private $db_name = "CANE_1718";
private $connectionInfo;
function db_connect(){ 
    $this->connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$this->db_name, "UID"=>$this->user_name, "PWD"=>$this->user_pwd);

    try{
        $sql_connect = sqlsrv_connect($this->server_name,$this->connectionInfo);
        if($sql_connect){
            echo 'Server Connected';
        }
        else{
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $x){
        print_r($x);
    }

}
```

}